# `Cannot instantiate non-constructior` Closure Compiler warning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, compiler-construction, instantiation

Dear folks, what should I do with these error warnings that Closure Compiler outputs?
Thank you very much for your ideas and code improtements on this particular type of error:

1. JSC_WRONG_ARGUMENT_COUNT: Function parseInt: called with 1 argument(s). Function requires at least 2 argument(s) and no more than 2 argument(s). at line 593 character 12
   `if (parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) < 7) {`
2. JSC_NOT_A_CONSTRUCTOR: cannot instantiate non-constructor at line 708 character 15
   `lightbox = new Lightbox(this, opts.lightbox);`
3. JSC_NOT_A_CONSTRUCTOR: cannot instantiate non-constructor at line 1265 character 19
   `var scroller = new Scroller($(this), opts);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Number 1:**
This warning means that you passed-in the wrong number of arguments in a function call.

[Here](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref.html) is a better explanation

**Number 2 & 3:**
The compiler expects all constructors to be marked with the JSDoc tag @constructor, like this:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function MyClass() {
  this.foo = 'bar';
}
var obj = new MyClass();
alert(obj.foo);
```

[Here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#constructor) is a better explanation.

Comment: So what do you do if the code is provided by a third party as a library that has been obfuscated?

Comment: That is a tough one, my friend.  You have no other choice than Ye Olde "Guess & Test".  Use your break-points & interrogate object properties...guess what they are and test the outcomes - Good Luck

Comment: You can make use of the setting jscomp_off and tell the compiler to ignore this requirement. The specific compiler checks you probably want off are globalThis and checkTypes. Using the command line the argument is --jscomp_off=checkTypes --jscomp_off=globalThis and using closure compiler for gulp would be jscomp_off: ['globalThis', 'checkTypes']

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, it wants you to pass two parameters to parseInt: value and radix. For 10-based numbers (which is your case), you need (don't really need but it wants you to) call

```
parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10)
```

Comment: You don't *have* to specify the second argument, but you should: "While this parameter is optional, always specify it to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.  Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @lwburk: I didn't say you have to specify two parameters, I said that closure compiler wants you to - that's what it complains about. Please remove your down vote.